# Run Python script forever, logging errors and restarting when crashes

Tags: python, node.js, python-2.7, meteor, forever

I have a python script that continuously process new data and writes to a mongodb. In the script, its a `while` loop and a `sleep` that runs the code continuously.

What is the recommended way to run the Python script forever, logging errors when they occur, and restarting when it crashes?

Will node.js's `forever` be suitable? I'm also running node/meteor on the same Ubuntu server.

Comment: Do you even need to start that python script from within node/meteor? If you just interact via the database, why not just start it separately?

Comment: @ChristianF The python script is not required to start from within node/meteor. I thought maybe node/meteor can help to manage the python script.

Answer (score 4):

**[supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)** is perfect for this sort of thing.  While I used to check that programs were still running every couple of minutes with a `cron` job, supervisord runs all programs in an in-process thread, so in the event your program terminates, supervisord will automatically restart the process.  I no longer need to parse the output of `ps` to see if a program crashed.

It has a simple declaritive config file and configurable logging.  By default it creates a log file for `your-program-name-stderr.log`  `your-program-name-stdout.log` which are automatically handled by logrotate when supervisord is installed from an OS package manager (Debian for me).

If you don't want to configure `supervisord`'s logging, you should look at [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) in python so you can control what goes into those files.

if you're on a debian derivative you should be able to install and start the daemon simply by executing `apt-get install supervisord` as root.

The config file is very straightforward too:

```
[program:myprogram]
command=/path/to/my/program/script 
directory=/path/to/my/program/base
user=myuser
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=True
```

`supervisorctl` also allows you to see what your program is doing interactively and can start and stop multiple programs with `supervisorctl start myprogram` etc

Answer (score 1):

Recently wrote something similar. The basic pattern I follow is

```
while True:
    try:
         #functionality
    except SpecificError:
        #log exception
    except: #catch everything else
    finally:
        time.sleep(600)
```

to handle reboots you can use init.d or cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a daemon, you should probably do it with this command:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html

You can spawn this from a System V /etc/init.d/ script, or use Upstart which is slowly replacing it.

Upstart: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html

System V: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-write-sys-v-init-script-to-start-stop-service.html

I find System V easier to write, but if this will ever be packaged and distributed in a debian file, I recommend writing an Upstart conf.

Definitely keep the sleep so it won't keep a grip on CPU load.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant to you, but I have been reading forever about how to do this and want to share somewhere what I did.

For me, the goal was to have a python script running always (on my Linux computer). The python script also has a "while True " loop in it which should theoretically run forever, but if it for any reason I cannot think of would crash, I want the script to restart. Also, when I restart the computer it should run the script.

I am not an expert but for me the best and most understandable was to use systemd (assuming you use Linux).

There are two nice examples of how to do this given [here](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/ewenchou/be496b2b73be801fd85267ef5471458c), showing how to write your .service files in either /etc/systemd/system or /lib/systemd/system. If you want to be completely correct you should take the former:

> " /etc/systemd/system/: units installed by the system administrator" [1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Service_types)

The documentation of systemd [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Service_types) is actually nice to read, even if you are not an expert.

Hope this helps someone!